# Synchronized Get Methods in Java

Tags: java, synchronization

This may seem like pedantry but is really me questioning my fundamental assumptions.. :)

In the [java documentation on synchronised methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), there is the following example:

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Is the `synchronized` keyword really required on the `value` method? Surely this is atomic and whether the value is retrieved before or after any calls to related methods on other threads makes little difference? Would the following suffice:

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

I understand that in a more complex case, where multiple private variables were being accessed then yes, it would be essential - but in this simple case, is it safe to assume that this can be simplified?

Also, I suppose that there is a risk that future modifications may require the value method to be synchronised and this could be forgotten, leading to bugs, etc, so perhaps this counts somewhat as defensive programming, but I am ignoring that aspect here.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, synchronized is really required on `value()`.  Otherwise a thread can call `value()` and get a stale answer.

> Surely this is atomic

For ints I believe so, but if value was a `long` or `double`, it's not.  It is even possible to see only some of the bits in the field updated!

> value is retrieved before or after any calls to related methods on other threads makes little difference?

Depends on your use case.  Often it does matter.

Some static analysis software such as FindBugs will flag this code as not having correct synchronization if `value()` isn't also synchronized.

Comment: But surely which thread accessed it first is somewhat arbitrary - so long as the value isn't *incorrect*? I agree that possibly for a multi-word value which requires more than 1 cycle to fetch, this may not be an atomic operation in which case it is required. I am assuming that fetching an int is atomic on the architecture.

Comment: Without the synchronization, the JVM is allowed to make all sorts of optimizations. For instance, let's say you have a loop `while (counter.get() == 0) { /* wait or something */ }`. You'd expect that an increment on another thread would release that lock, right? If the getter isn't synchronized, the JVM is free to (and often will) optimize the getter to read from a local register, and thus never see any increment.

Answer (score 2):

synchronized is required for both reading and writing a variable from another thread. This guarantees

1. that values will be copied from cache or registers to RAM (granted this is important for writing not reading)
2. it establishes that writes will happen before reads if they appear so in code. Otherwise the compiler is free to rearrange lines of bytecode for optimization

Check *Effective Java* Item 66 for a more detailed analysis